# Converting Flash video to HTML5

Tags: flash, html, safari

I have a flash video(.swf) on my website and I want it to convert into such a format so that it remain available from iphone/ipad. Is there any possible way of doing so? Can I convert it into HTML5? If yes can anyone suggest the process and if no, can anyone suggest any other method?

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely possible to convert flash to html 5, depending on what it is you want to do. A good example of this being done is www.zombo.com (flash) -> http://html5zombo.com/ (html 5).

If you look at the source on html5zombo.com there is an explanation of how he did it (reprinted below)

> HTML5zombo.com
>               Bertrand Fan (bertrand@fan.net)
>               5/19/2010

```
        I wanted zombo.com on my iPad. That is all.

        ===================================================================
        How I did it, for nerds:
        ===================================================================

        Watched the Net tab for zombo.com in Firebug            

        wget http://www.zombo.com/inrozxa.swf
        wget http://www.zombo.com/welcomeclip.swf

        Opened them in SWFRIP to extract the MP3 and SVG representations of the logo and spinner.
        Opened the SVG files in Adobe Illustrator (ironic, I know), tweaked a bit, exported new SVG files

        Copy-pasted the SVG contents into this HTML file, tweaked the attributes a bit

        Wrote the JS code to rotate the SVG spinner

        Converted the MP3 to OGG using oggenc2 (not really necessary for the iPad, but apparently for Firefox)

        Discovered that the iPad does not respect autoplay on HTML5 audio tags, crafted a javascript link for iPads

        wget http://www.zombo.com/favicon.ico

        ===================================================================
        References:
        ===================================================================

        http://www.zombo.com/
        http://twitter.com/zombocom
        http://sourceforge.net/projects/swfrip/
        http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html
        http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/
        http://emacsformacosx.com/
        http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/
```

Comment: While this is a (lengthy) solution, it involves a lot of skill and patience, and is essentially not a conversion perse, I think our poster is after a tool to convert the files. Other than that, I like the above solution a lot and am not knocking it, I think we can all learn something from it.

Comment: But this only covers extremely simple animation [spinning, motion tween]...  What if he has skeletal animation, color tween, tons of layers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have both. Here is a video tutorial showing how to have Flash video but with an HTML5 fallback http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=128 [EDIT] assuming that this is indeed a video, and you will need to convert it to a suitable video file

Answer (score 1):

We've had good results with [Gordon](http://github.com/tobeytailor/gordon). Did work for simple videos, but we weren't able to get anything interactive to work.

Comment: Can you share, if it is possible, how you used Gordon and for what?

Answer (score 0):

[www.doom9.org](http://www.doom9.org) has all the video conversion tutorials you need

**Edit:** do you mean *actual* flash video (flv), as in the format or just flash (swf) ?

**Edit re comment** OK, if there's no interaction you can still convert it to an html5 friendly video format, have a Google, there are plenty of converters. You probably want to use Flash as a fallback in the absence of an html5 compatible browser, this way you support the old (and new) crap that Microsoft push, and the modern standards compliant browsers.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, it is just flash(.swf) and does not have any interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no no no you cannot. Flash uses an entirely separate language, Actionscript, which is completely different to that of HTML or XHTML! Actionscript can almost be seen as a language similar in properties to Javascript, while XHTML can almost be viewed as a descender of XML, although it is **not** XML, but you get my drift.

Unfortunately in your case I think you will need to re-develop your website or provide an alternative page for mobile users. You could always have a landing page and detect if the user is no a mobile device like the iPhone, Android etc etc and redirect them to a site that is optimized for their needs.

I think a flash to HTML or XHTML converter would be much appreciated by many of us as it's is more common than you'd like to think for a client to now want his/her Flash website as static or XHTML.

Comment: Looking at the first answer, if your flash site simply has animation, there are a mound of tools that will convert it to a video format (Flash itself can) and you can show THAT to iPhone users in a  video format they can read. If your flash has interactivity, this is out of the question of course.

Comment: "When a distinguished but elderly scientist states that something is
  possible, he is almost certainly right.  When he states that something
  is impossible, he is very probably wrong."
     - Arthur C. Clarke's First Law

Comment: @StephenPaulger - If you'd noticed the comment below my post you would have also noted my reference to that fact that it is NOT impossible if just animation, but not possible if it has interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Get the video using swftools' swfextract:

http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Swfextract